# Ring structure of $\mathbb{Z}$ adjoined $\alpha : \alpha^3+\alpha^2+1=0, \alpha^2+\alpha=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Here I tried using the division algorithm:
$\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1=\alpha(\alpha^2+\alpha)+1$. Does it mean that (since $\alpha$ and $1$ are both in $R[\alpha]$) $(\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1) = (\alpha^2+\alpha)$?

And then the problem is to find out what is $R[x]/(x^2+x)$, but that is just $\mathbb{Z}[-1]=\mathbb{Z}$?

I am not sure if this proof is correct, because it seems like it does not use any properties of the quotient and remainder that I got.

Comment: The two equations together imply that $1=0$.

Comment: >  Does it mean that (since $\alpha$ and $1$ are both in $R[\alpha]$) $(\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1) = (\alpha^2+\alpha)$?

No. In fact neither ideal is contained in the other. It seems like you wanted to use the equation you wrote to deduce that $\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + 1 \in (\alpha^2 + \alpha)$, but this would only go through if you had $1 \in (\alpha^2 + \alpha)$ (which is false). Even if this worked, you would only get $(\alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + 1) \subseteq (\alpha^2 + \alpha)$, and you would need to do more work to establish the reverse inclusion.